# Typescript: Object key name containing spaces

Tags: typescript

In globals.ts, I have:

```
export const Roles = { Manager: 2, "Customer Service": 4 }
const r = Roles["Customer Service"]; // ok
```

In the consuming file, I have:

```
import { Roles } from "./globals";
const m = Roles.Manager;  // ok
const M = Roles["Manager"]; // ok
const r = Roles["Customer Service"]; // not ok
```

The last line gives:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ Manager: number; "Customer Service": number; ...' has no index signature.

Why is this not allowed? How do I reference an element with a key that contains spaces?

Comment: Works fine in http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/, even with `noImplicitAny` turned on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect in your actual code, the property is keyed off of some non-constant variable. With `noImplicitAny`, this yields the same error.

```
let key = "Customer Service"; // type string
const r = Roles[key]; // error
```

You need to constrain `key` the name to the actual keys of the type.

```
let key: keyof typeof Roles = "Customer Service"; // type "Manager"|"Customer Service"
const r = Roles[key]; // ok
```

Otherwise, the literal `"Customer Service"` should satisfy the key type and there should be no error.

Comment: Sorry for sending all on a wild goose chase. It was a typo error.